# How do I echo the post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

`<?php $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID ); if  $post_type == 'project' : echo 'Work'; ?>`

How can I make the above work? I want it so that if the post type is 'projects', then it echoes 'Work'.

Also, I want to add another `if post type is 'movies' then it echoes 'Film'` on top of that.

Comment: Maybe this is just a typo here, but in one place you say the post type is `project` and in another place you say `projects`. If it's `projects` and you're saying `if $post_type == 'project'` then it's not going to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as far as I can tell you've got a syntax error there. Try this:

```
<?php $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID ); if ($post_type == 'project') echo 'Work'; ?>
```

Also, make sure to check out what eileen.carpenter said in the comment to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use native labels that you set up for custom post type?

```
$post_type = get_post_type_object($post->post_type);
echo $post_type->labels->singular_name;
```